# MySQL assign variable

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

What I am trying to do is, I have a design_sheet as a table in database and multiple tables in the format

'sb16im2yr_c',COUNTYID,'y',YEAR,'_',METHOD,'_9653_20MY_out'

in the design_sheet it gives us COUNTYID, YEAR, METHOD in each row

so I try to use this to give the input table for each row

```
set @COUNTYDATA = concat('sb16im2yr_c',@COUNTYID,'y',@YEAR,'_',@METHOD,'_9653_20MY_out')
```

Then using

```
set @str = concat(BALA)
```

to help me insert data from each table to a summary table 'INSERT INTO `',@SUMMARY,'`.`',@SUMMARY_TB

Overall code is here

```
SET @n = 0;
SET @COUNTYID =  (Select countyID From `sb16im2yr_summary`.`design_sheet` 
    where year=@YEAR limit @n,@n+1);
select @COUNTYID;
SET @METHOD =  (Select TMD_HPMS From `sb16im2yr_summary`.`design_sheet` 
    where year=@YEAR limit @n,@n+1);
SET @EXT =  (Select IM frequency From `sb16im2yr_summary`.`design_sheet` 
    where year=@YEAR limit @n,@n+1);
set @COUNTYDATA = concat('sb16im2yr_c',@COUNTYID,'y',@YEAR,'_',@METHOD,'_9653_20MY_out');
set @str = concat('INSERT INTO `',@SUMMARY,'`.`',@SUMMARY_TB,'` 
    (`MOVESRunName`, `MOVESRunID`, `outputTimePeriod`, `timeUnits`, `distanceUnits`, 
    `massUnits`, `energyUnits`, `runSpecFileName`, `runSpecDescription`, `runSpecFileDateTime`, 
    `runDateTime`, `scale`, `minutesDuration`, `defaultDatabaseUsed`, `masterVersion`, 
    `masterComputerID`, `masterIDNumber`, `domain`, `domainCountyID`, `domainCountyName`, 
    `domainDatabaseServer`, `domainDatabaseName`, `expectedDONEFiles`, `retrievedDONEFiles`, 
    `models`) 
SELECT "',@COUNTYDATA,'",          
    `MOVESRunID`, `outputTimePeriod`, `timeUnits`, `distanceUnits`, `massUnits`, 
    `energyUnits`, `runSpecFileName`, `runSpecDescription`, `runSpecFileDateTime`, 
    `runDateTime`, `scale`, `minutesDuration`, `defaultDatabaseUsed`, `masterVersion`, 
    `masterComputerID`, `masterIDNumber`, `domain`, `domainCountyID`, `domainCountyName`, 
    `domainDatabaseServer`, `domainDatabaseName`, `expectedDONEFiles`, `retrievedDONEFiles`, 
    `models` 
FROM `',@COUNTYDATA,'`.`movesrun`;');
PREPARE stmt from @str;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Loops are generally not the solution to problems in SQL.  You should ask another question and explain what you want to do in the loop, with sample data and desired results.  If you really do need a loop (say you are running a stored procedure on each row), you should be using a cursor.

Comment: I modified my question and make it more clear than previous one, but it is very difficult to explain. I will also look into cursor thank you